# How to handle memory leak when using angular.js ngRepeat and Routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular is leaking DOM elements when I'm using ngRepeat with the Route service.

Our app has a table with search results. When the user clicks the next button on the pagination control, the app changes the route. So `http://website/results/1` will become `http://website/results/2` this causes angular to call compile on the ngRepeat directive which clears it's cache. The DOM elements and $scope objects in the cache are sticking around and leaking.

You can see this same issue on `http://docs.angularjs.org/api/`

Navigate to the site above, open dev tools and start the timeline. Then start clicking on the navigation on the left hand side. Start at the top and keep clicking until you get to the bottom of the nav then go back up.

You will see the DOM Node count just keep growing and never gets fully garbaged collected.

This is a real issue.

My question is: does anybody now how to fix this? Is there a work around?

Also, as a side note but still related is that angular appears to leak each element that is wrapping an inline expression. {{objectOnTheScope}}

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to nested ng-repeat memory leak. 
See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1313#issuecomment-10378451